# Error al insertar registros en SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

Tengo una clase donde defino una conexión MySQL (origen) y una conexión a SQL Server (donde quiero insertar).

Éste es el código de la clase relativo a la conexión con el servidor MS SQL Server:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class MysqlClass
 */
class MysqlClass

{

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public static function getConnectionMSSQL() : PDO
    {

        try
        {
            $conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=localhost.test;Database=test', 'user', 'pwd1234');
            $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
        }


        return $conn;
    }

}
```

El problema que tengo es que el bucle del MySQL lo hace bien, pero solo me inserta un registro en SQL Server y después me lanza este error:

> **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. in /var/www/html/test/test.php:26**

El fichero PHP que ejecuto es éste, donde leo de la base de datos MySQL e intento guardar en la base de datos SQL Server.

```
<?php

    include ('class/MysqlClass.php');

    $connSqlserver = MysqlClass::getConnectionMSSQL();
    $connMysql = MysqlClass::getConnectionMySQL();

    $sqlOrigin = "SELECT * from cars";

    $stmt = $connMysql->prepare($sqlOrigin);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {

        if($stmt->columnCount() <= 0) {
            $stmt->nextRowset();
        }

        $tipo = $row['tipo'];
        $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $sql = "Insert into dbo.cars(tipo,nombre)  values ( :tipo, :nombre";

        $stmt= $connSqlserver->prepare($sql);

        try {

            $stmt->bindParam(':tipo',$tipo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            var_dump('execute SQL');

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            var_dump('error **************');
            var_dump($e);
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Creo que tienes un error de sintasis SQL en `Insert into dbo.cars(tipo,nombre)  values ( :tipo, :nombre`. Deberías cerrar el paréntesis: `Insert into dbo.cars(tipo,nombre)  values ( :tipo, :nombre)`. Por cierto, estás desaprovechando la mayor ventaja de las consultas preparadas, preparar la consulta ANTES del bucle y asignar valores y ejecutarla dentro del bucle tantas veces como lo necesitas sin tener que preparar de nuevo la consulta. Además, estás reasignando la variable `$stmt` en `$stmt= $connSqlserver->prepare($sql);`, por lo que fallará el `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())`.

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista veo dos problemas en tu código:

- La consulta SQL está mal (falta el paréntesis final).
- Estás sobreescribiendo la variable `$stmt` que contiene el resultado de la consulta SQL al servidor MySQL.

Además, estás desaprovechando una de las ventajas de las consultas preparadas, que es preparar una vez la consulta y ejecutarla múltiples veces con diferentes valores asignados a los marcadores.

Tu código podría mejorarse de la siguiente manera (he dejado comentarios explicando los cambios o mejoras):

```
<?php
include 'class/MysqlClass.php';

$connSqlserver = MysqlClass::getConnectionMSSQL();
$connMysql = MysqlClass::getConnectionMySQL();

$sqlOrigin = "SELECT * FROM cars";

$stmt = $connMysql->prepare($sqlOrigin);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();

/* Preparamos la consulta SQL una única vez, tras corregir el paréntesis final */
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.cars(tipo,nombre) VALUES (:tipo, :nombre)";
/* He nombrado a esta consulta $stmt_mssql para diferenciarla de la del MySQL */
$stmt_mssql = $connSqlserver->prepare($sql);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    try {
        /* Solo necesitamos reasignar los marcadores y ejecutar la consulta */
        $stmt_mssql->bindParam(':tipo', $row['tipo']);
        $stmt_mssql->bindParam(':nombre', $row['nombre']);
        $stmt_mssql->execute();
        echo 'execute SQL', PHP_EOL;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
}
```